# Ellipse equation from two tangent lines

Tags: conic-sections

Is there any way to find the equation of an ellipse, when only two tangent lines are given?

Comment: No. Even a circle would be undefined. For an ellipse, you need five conditions.

Comment: Got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ellipse will not be unique, e.g. when the $x$- and $y$- axis are the two tangent lines.